# Open git local repository programmatically in visual studio

Tags: git, visual-studio, visual-studio-extensions

My VisualStudio Solution and project files are outside Git Repository source directory.
So, Git repository is not detected while opening solution file. Every time I am opening Git Repository manually by using Git->Open Local Repository menu.
I have tried Git.OpenLocalRepository with arguments, but it not accepting arguments.
Any suggestions how to associate Git Repository with solution.

I have tried this, but it is showing ActiveRepositories and it's read-only.

```
    var gitExt = GetService(typeof(IGitExt)) as IGitExt;
    if (gitExt != null)
    {
        var activeRepo = gitExt.ActiveRepositories.FirstOrDefault();
        if (activeRepo != null)
        {
            // You now have access to the active Git repository.
            // You can perform various Git operations using the activeRepo object.
        }
        else { }
    }
```

And `Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Git.CoreServices.ISccRepositoryManagerService` is not public at present.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

I think you need use this:

[DTE.ExecuteCommand(String, String) Method](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/envdte.dte.executecommand?view=visualstudiosdk-2022#envdte-dte-executecommand(system-string-system-string))

[image]

So it should be like:

`DTE.ExecuteCommand("Git.OpenLocalRepository", gitRepoPath);`

Comment: I have tried this already, Git.OpenLocalRepository is not accepting any arguments.
Exception: System.Reflection.RuntimeMethodInfo.get_ReturnTypeCustomAttributes cannot be called in this context.
Without argument, it's opening Select Repository UI.